# Semantic UI side bar color is black when color property is set to white

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

Hi I am trying to change color to white for the side bar that I have implemented using semantic UI , Currently I have used hex code = **#FFFFFF** and RGB color = **rgb(255, 255, 255)** but both are setting the color to black , how can i change this color to white .
Bellow is my sidebar

```js
<Sidebar
              as={Segment}
              animation={"push"}
              direction="left"
              icon="labeled"
              inverted
              vertical
              visible={toggle}
              color="rgb(255, 255, 255)" // here is my issue
            >
                <displaycomponent></displaycomponent>
</Sidebar>
```

you can see the same issue on the documentation examples here : https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar/#states-visible

expect white all other color seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an alternate fix for this , You just have to add the color on your child component ( in my case its  ) and later you adjust padding on your side bar like bellow

```js
<Sidebar
              as={Segment}
              animation={"push"}
              direction="left"
              icon="labeled"
              inverted
              vertical
              style={{paddingTop:"0",paddingBottom:"0"}}
              visible={toggle}
              color="rgb(255, 255, 255)"
            >
               <displaycomponent></displaycomponent>
            </Sidebar>
```

**Easiest fix is just remove** **inverted**